# Trying to setup diagnostic settings for activity logs in ARM template

Tags: c#, azure, azure-rm-template

I've been trying to create a template for a logger function app in Azure, the basic idea is that it'll forward all activity log category info along with all audit log info using event hubs as triggers, I've gotten down most of the template, but I keep hitting the following error when it comes to the diagnostic settings part:

**The resource type '/' does not support diagnostic settings.**

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I've only started working with azure for a short while, and am afraid I'm misunderstanding how diagnostic settings are created in an ARM template. I can't seem to find any template or documentation online about this, and am at a loss...

Here's an excerpt:

````
...
  "variables": {
    "eventHubNamespaceName": "azure-logger",
    "auditEventHubName": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), '/', 'audit-logs')]",
    "activityEventHubName": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), '/', 'activity-logs')]",
    "authRuleResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/authorizationRules', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), 'RootManageSharedAccessKey')]",
    "auditAuthorizationRuleId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', variables('eventHubNamespaceName') , 'audit-logs', 'default')]",
    "activityAuthorizationRuleId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', variables('eventHubNamespaceName') , 'activity-logs', 'default')]"
  },
"resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('eventHubNamespaceName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces",
      "apiVersion": "2021-06-01-preview",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard"
      },
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "status": "Active"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs",
          "apiVersion": "2021-06-01-preview",
          "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), '/', 'audit-logs')]",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "messageRetentionInDays": 1,
            "partitionCount": 1
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules",
              "apiVersion": "2021-06-01-preview",
              "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), '/', 'audit-logs','/','default')]",
              "properties": {
                "rights": [ "Manage", "Listen", "Send" ]
              },
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs',  variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), 'audit-logs')]"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs",
          "apiVersion": "2021-06-01-preview",
          "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), '/', 'activity-logs')]",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "messageRetentionInDays": 1,
            "partitionCount": 1
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules",
              "apiVersion": "2021-06-01-preview",
              "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), '/', 'activity-logs','/','default')]",
              "properties": {
                "rights": [ "Manage", "Listen", "Send" ]
              },
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs',  variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), 'activity-logs')]"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'),'activity-logs')]",
      "properties": {
        "eventHubName": "activity-logs",
        "eventHubAuthorizationRuleId": "[variables('activityAuthorizationRuleId')]",
        "logs": [
          {
            "category": "Administrative",
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "category": "Security",
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "category": "ServiceHealth",
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "category": "Alert",
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "category": "Recommendation",
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "category": "Policy",
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "category": "Autoscale",
            "enabled": true
          },
          {
            "category": "ResourceHealth",
            "enabled": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]
...```
````

Answer (score 0):

Diagnostic settings for Activity logs are created for a **subscription**, **not for a resource group** like settings for Azure resources. Therefore, when you check the [Diagnostic setting for Activity log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-manager-diagnostic-settings#diagnostic-setting-for-activity-log) in this document, you will find that you can deploy Azure Resource Manager templates using any valid method including PowerShell and CLI. **Diagnostic settings for Activity log must deploy to a subscription using  `az deployment create`  for CLI or  `New-AzDeployment`  for PowerShell**.

And the template should look like as following :

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "settingName": {
          "type": "String"
        },
        "workspaceId": {
          "type": "String"
        },
        "storageAccountId": {
          "type": "String"
        },
        "eventHubAuthorizationRuleId": {
          "type": "String"
        },
        "eventHubName": {
          "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('settingName')]",
            "properties": {
                "workspaceId": "[parameters('workspaceId')]",
                "storageAccountId": "[parameters('storageAccountId')]",
                "eventHubAuthorizationRuleId": "[parameters('eventHubAuthorizationRuleId')]",
                "eventHubName": "[parameters('eventHubName')]",
                "logs": [
                    {
                        "category": "Administrative",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Security",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "ServiceHealth",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Alert",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Recommendation",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Policy",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "Autoscale",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "ResourceHealth",
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You should have a Parameter file if you follow the above template.

Also note that when virtual networks are enabled Diagnostic Settings  can't access Event Hubs resources. You have to enable the Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall setting in Event Hub, so that Diagnostic Settings (Azure Monitor Services) is granted access to your Event Hubs resources.

Comment: That's the template I based mine on, but I did try yours separately only removing workspaceId (I did not have one when I created the same stack manually through the portal, so I'm assuming I don't need one now) I still get the same error deploying using the github action provided by Azure (is it that I must use az deployment create instead?): Error: "The resource type '/' does not support diagnostic settings."